# How to transform Multiline string into object

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, object

Hello guys I have one problem which gets me confused, sorry if I am asking a obvious question for you but please help me if you can..

```
{"value":1,"text":"first"},
{"value":2,"text":"second"},
{"value":3,"text":"third"},
{"value":4,"text":"fourth"} 
...
```

I have string which looks like that, I need to parse this string, when there is just one line I have no problem with JSON.parse but is there a way to parse whole string?

EDIT:

here is my client side:

```
$.post(path,{"loadComps":"*"},function(data){
console.log(data);
$('.dev_comp').editable({
source: data
}); 
});
```

and here is what I get from console.log

```
[ 
{"value":1,"text":"somename"}, 
{"value":2,"text":"somename"}, 
{"value":3,"text":"somename"}, 
....
{"value":1400,"text":"somename"}, 
{"value":1401,"text":"somename"}, 
]
```

Error log:

> jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5 GET mywebpage.com/eng/[%20%7B%22value%22:1,%22text%22:%22%20%E1%83%A1%E1…%E1%83%90%E1%83%AE%E1%83%90%E1%83%AB%E1%83%94%22%7D%20%20]?_=1464096474491 414 (Request-URI Too Large)

Comment: `JSON.parse` will quite happily deal with a valid multiline string.  Can you see if you can create a [mcve]?

Comment: Did you try the following: `JSON.parse("["+my_multiline_string+"]")` ? It would return an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the string being multiline. The problem is that the objects in your JSON string are not placed in an array. This:

```
var myJsonString = "[{"value":1,"text":"first"},
{"value":1,"text":"first"},
{"value":3,"text":"third"},
{"value":4,"text":"fourth"} ]"
```

is the same thing as this:

```
var myJsonString = "[{"value":1,"text":"first"}, {"value":1,"text":"first"}{"value":3,"text":"third"},{"value":4,"text":"fourth"} ];
```

What you're missing is that the objects in the JSON string need to be placed in an array []. If you can't change the source of the JSON string to add `[]` around it then add on `[` before and one `]` after the string before parsing it:

```
var myJsonString = "[" + myJsonString + "]";
var arr = JSON.parse(myJsonString);
```

Comment: You have syntax error you can't have double quotes inside double quotes.